# How do I setup the routing for a 404 page?

Tags: php, oop, routes

With some tutorials on the internet I created a simple router with php. The code works fine but I tried to route a 404 page if the file does not exist. My code below

index file (php)

```
include 'router.php';
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$router = new router($request);

$router->get('/','app/home');
$router->get('post','app/post');   
$router->get('hello','app/hello');
```

router file (php)

```
class router
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function get($route, $file)
    {
        $uri = trim($this->request, "/");
        $uri = explode("/", $uri);

        if($uri[1] == trim($route, "/")) {
            array_shift($uri);
            $args = $uri;
            if(file_exists($file . '.php')) {
                require_once $file .'.php';
            } else {
                require_once  '404.php';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code does not show the 404 page but only the files that exist. Please can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

First of all your code seems to be vulnerable to 'file inclusion'. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion

And second, it **should** work fine, my crystal ball tells me, the `404.php` file is not readable for some reason (it's not there or there are permission problems). To see what is going on - enable error reporting i.e. put this in your php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = -1
display_errors = On
```

Or add this somewhere at the beginning of your app/script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```